# Is my answer of finding domain of $\frac{x^2}{2x-1}<1$ correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{x^2}{2x-1}<1$$

I have to find the domain. I got $0<x<2$ and $x\neq 1/2$. But answer is given is $0<x<2$. Which one is true?

Comment: "Domain" is a concept for functions, not inequalities. One would say "find the domain of a function" or "find the solution set for an inequality", but not "find the domain for an inequality".

Comment: Thanks Jack....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $x \neq 1/2$.

Then if $x > 1/2$, you have $2x-1>0$ and $x^2<2x-1$, *i.e* $(x-1)^2<0$, impossible

And if $x < 1/2$, you have $2x-1<0$ and $x^2>2x-1$, *i.e* $(x-1)^2>0$, always true.

Finally you find that $x < 1/2$.

Comment: wow! thanks... i did not thought that!

Answer (score 0):

write $$1-\frac{x^2}{2x-1}=\frac{2x-1-x^2}{2x-1}=-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2x-1}=\frac{(x-1)^2}{1-2x}>0$$ can you finish?