# solution set of the inequality $\frac{x^2-1}{(x+2)(x+3)}>2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Question: Find the solution set of the inequality $$\frac{x^2-1}{(x+2)(x+3)}>2$$

From the answer given in the [previous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372464/is-my-answer-of-finding-domain-correct) problem I got this:

First $x\neq -2,-3$. solving the equation I get $-(2\sqrt{3}+5)<x<(2\sqrt{3}-5)$.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac { x^{ 2 }-1 }{ \left( x+2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  } >2\\ \frac { x^{ 2 }-1 }{ \left( x+2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  } -2>0\\ \frac { -{ x }^{ 2 }-10x-13 }{ \left( x+2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  } >0\\ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }+10x+13 }{ \left( x+2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  } <0\\ \frac { \left( x+2\sqrt { 3 } +5 \right) \left( x+5-2\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( x+2 \right) \left( x+3 \right)  }{ { \left( x+2 \right)  }^{ 2 }{ \left( x+3 \right)  }^{ 2 } } <0\\ \left( x+2\sqrt { 3 } +5 \right) \left( x+5-2\sqrt { 3 }  \right) \left( x+2 \right) \left( x+3 \right) <0\\ \\ \\ \\ $$can you take from here? (your answer is wrong by the way)

Comment: The inequality should be flipped between steps 3 and 4?

Comment: the inequality flipped, i think!

Comment: Your fourth step is wrong.  When you multiply an inequality by a negative  number, the direction of the inequality is reversed.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig,thank you,it was typo,now i fixed